# Select Dropdown going out of screen in mobile view

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I got select dropdown which is going out of screen in mobile view. I'm using bootstrap class `form-control`. My code is as below

```
<select name="service" formControlName="service" class="form-control shadow-none" style="width:100%">
      <option value="Select" selected>Select</option>
      <option value="Sedan" selected>Sedan</option>
      <option value="SUV" selected>SUV</option>
      <option value="Mini" selected>Mini</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Any kind of help will be appreciated...

Comment: If you are viewing it in Chrome/firefox browser, then dont worry as this is just a small bug in the stimulation. When it actually renders in mobile view, it will the normal properties which you have specified.

Comment: @AKNair i an worried as it is simulating unexpectedly so. I hope it works in actual rendering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using a select element then each phone operating system will render the list of items using its default styling.

**iOS example** [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uTE3.png)

**Android example** [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzKm4.jpg)

Answer (score 6):

This is only because of you are check the mobile view in Desktop browser.

In real devices this is not causing any problem and adjust width as per the device width.

and the select options list opens differently as per the OS means in android devices it opens as a drop-down list and in IOs devices it open like a pop-over.

try to open this page in real device not in mobile view of desktop browser.

I hope this answer will clear your all doubts.

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes these occurences happen if you're working on responsive web applications. These is likely caused by browser incompatibility that results to an abnormal behavior.

I suggest use the property **auto**

```
<select name="service" formControlName="service" class="form-control shadow-none" style="width:auto">
      <option value="Select" selected>Select</option>
      <option value="Sedan" selected>Sedan</option>
      <option value="SUV" selected>SUV</option>
      <option value="Mini" selected>Mini</option>
</select>
```

**Edit:**
Try putting position: absolute with width: 100%. should pull that div outside of the container. You're asking an element to stretch wider than its parent, which is generally not recommended practice.

Comment: It's not working, if i give width or not. I just put in my code to show that I tried by giving width as well.

Comment: try putting position: absolute with width: 100%. should pull that div outside of the container. You're asking an element to stretch wider than its parent, which is generally not recommended practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using media-queries for mobile devices and give fixed width for form elements when loaded below certain resolutions:
`@mediaonlyscreenand(max-width:600px){select{width:200px!important;}}`

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. When you view the browser's moblie mode, there is a mechanism that clearly shows your selection and drop-down menu. These sections look different when you open them with a real mobile device.

There is another way you can manage this. That is, you will manually create a selection or drop-down menu not with the select tag but with other tags.

Answer (score -2):

try another browser then chrome the error will be solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).